# ADX: Out Of Memory Failure while processing the query: Array dimensions exceeded supported range

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I'm trying to find the reason for this error happening.
I have a function in ADX that is triggered when data is ingested into a table.
Each night we add about 100k rows. This function has two lookups and is unable to complete.

Any tips on how to troubleshoot this? Is to too many rows or columns? Any error logs I can investigate to figure it out? Is it a scaling issue on the cluster? I would expect ADX to handle 100k rows in a trigger.

Comment: This question is too generic. Please share the ClientActivityId of the query that failed, and we'll investigate. In general, you can look for query best practices on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/best-practices  (by the way, ADX can easily handle queries over tables with trillions of records, in split seconds, so the number or records/columns isn't the issue here).

Comment: Thanks for the response, would activityId: "5fa46fd8-4b31-4838-b7bd-03ed6071e7f2", and subActivityId: "60f061d1-592e-401e-933e-35b1d0d964d9" help?

Comment: Yes, this helps. Ziad from our team will reply shortly, with the solution.
By the way, the ClientActivityId was "KE.RunQuery;f029a3b5-fab3-49a4-a390-5330f6492584" (you can see it in the bottom-right corner in Kusto Explorer, when the query completes), but we found it using the IDs you provided.

Comment: Thank you @SlavikN that's excellent support!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The failure is due to a limitation of the lookup operator which is transformed internally into a broadcast join.

Please have a look at the docs of [broadcast join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/broadcastjoin) here which states that the left side of the join (in broadcast join) which is the right side of lookup (in lookup operator) should be up to a few 10s of MBs.

In the query above, it has 2 lookup operators where each one has a right side of a big result (one is ~135MB and the other is ~400MB) which causes the query to hit that limitation of broadcast join.

In order to estimate the right side size in your case before deciding if to use lookup & broadcast join / regular join operator, you can use this query:

```
RightSideExpression 
| project col1, col2, ..., colN
| summarize sum(estimate_data_size(*))
```

In order to fix the above query, you need to switch to [join operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/joinoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer) and make sure to follow [query best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/best-practices) regarding keeping the smaller dataset on the left side of the join.

P.S. We'll update the doc for `lookup` to mention the limitation.

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem. I tested two different solutions. First, replace `lookup` with regular `join`. Second, I limited the lookup tables with a where clause because a fixed date was a predicate for both tables. This also limited the size of the dimension table. 
Is both reliable solutions, or should `join` be used?

Comment: Both approaches are absolutely valid. My guess is that the performance of the second one will proably be better, but I suggest you test it. Regardless of which approach you choose, adding a filter on the other table is a good idea, as it will make the query take less resources.